# How can I instrument a function using OpenTelemetry and SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, sveltekit, open-telemetry

### Context

I am using SvelteKit and would like to instrument it with OpenTelemetry. I have tried using the NodeSDK for automatic instrumentation and it works; I am able to see some automatically created traces in my Grafana Tempo backend, but they aren't very useful.

### Question

I specifically want to instrument some functions in my +page.svelte files or my components (which may run on either the client or the server) so that they clearly show up as their own traces.

Is anyone able to tell me how I can manually instrument a function inside a +page.svelte file so it is the first span in a trace? (My attempt at getting this to work is in the +page.svelte file in the gist)

### Code

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/liamwh/980b034106030f774a3563ec5fbd441e) with my current code.

### Extra context

The following is an exerpt from the linked gist to show the code I'd love to work. I'd expect this to show up in Grafana Tempo as a trace called `getContactsAndUpdateStore`, but I don't see this trace, only the automatically generated ones.

```
    async function getContactsAndUpdateStore(userId: string) {
        const tracer = opentelemetry.trace.getTracer('default');
        console.log(tracer);
        return tracer.startActiveSpan('getContactsAndUpdateStore', async (span) => {
            try {
                span.setAttribute('userId', userId);
                const users = await getContacts(userId);
                contacts.set(users);
                span.addEvent('Contacts fetched successfully');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching contacts:', error);
                if (error instanceof Error) {
                    // Record the exception in the span if it's an Error
                    span.recordException(error);
                    span.setStatus({ code: SpanStatusCode.ERROR, message: error.message });
                } else {
                    // If it's not an Error instance, stringify if possible.
                    span.setStatus({ code: SpanStatusCode.ERROR, message: String(error) });
                }
                contacts.set([]); // Fallback in case of error
            } finally {
                console.log(span);
                span.end();
                console.log(span);
            }
        });
    }
```

`console.log(tracer)` produces:
[image: tracer]

`console.log(span)` produces:
[image: span]

I tried using [auto-instrumentations-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web) as well, but whenever I imported it I got an issue and was unable to get it working. However I have a suspicison that I somehow need to handle getting the tracer differently depending on whether the code is running on the client or server, however I'm a bit out of my depth here and would sincerely appreciate any help!